# Prevent backspace from navigating back in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, backspace

I faced this issue in my AngularJS webapp.

When a user enters a page with a form to fill and he starts typing, if he presses the backspace key and the focus is not on the input text, then the page goes to the previous state.

I looked up [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495219/how-can-i-prevent-the-backspace-key-from-navigating-back) using jQuery, but it doesn't seem the appropiate way for achieve this in AngularJS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is `$document` in angular js:

```
angular.module('yourModule', [])
  .controller('yourController', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document) {
      $document.on('keydown', function(e){
          if(e.which === 8 && ( e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT" && e.target.nodeName !== "SELECT" ) ){ // you can add others here inside brackets.
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      });

    }
  ]);
```

### [Plnkr Demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXtiJNI0a73c0SwIQ7mI?p=preview)

You can see in the demo i have used only for `"INPUT"` nodeName and it does not prevent the default of the backspace key on text input but not on `textarea` because we have not handled it in the condition.

Comment: @seb how come is that *elementary error*? frankly speaking this is just for backspace and anyone elem whether it is input or select.

Comment: @seb just curious to know is there anything in a webpage where you can focus two elements at same time, because afaik not possible. So using `&&` fails.

Comment: See Tolya's answer. e.which === 8 && e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT" || e.target.nodeName !== "SELECT" is equivalent to (e.which === 8 && e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT") || e.target.nodeName !== "SELECT", so it is true whatever the key pressed if e.target.nodeName !== "SELECT.

Comment: you should consider editable tags also in if condition.

if (e.which === 8 && !e.target.isContentEditable && (!rx.test(e.target.tagName) || e.target.disabled || e.target.readOnly)) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

Answer (score 9):

I can't comment "accepted answer", but it will work not right, as condition

```
e.which === 8 && e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT" || e.target.nodeName !== "SELECT"
```

with logic error, so you can use

```
e.which === 8 && e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT" && e.target.nodeName !== "SELECT"
```

or answer that wrote @ThisIsMarkSantiago.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below script in your controller

```
var rx = /INPUT|SELECT|TEXTAREA/i;

$document.on("keydown keypress", function(e){
    if( e.which == 8 ){ // 8 == backspace
        if(!rx.test(e.target.tagName) || e.target.disabled || e.target.readOnly ){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Or you can use Jquery

```
  $(function(){
      var regx = /INPUT|SELECT|TEXTAREA/i;

      $(document).bind("keydown keypress", function(e){
          if( e.which == 8 ){ // 8 == backspace
              if(!regx.test(e.target.tagName) || e.target.disabled || e.target.readOnly ){
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
          }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer here:
[How can I disabling backspace key press on all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309693/disabling-backspace-key-works-in-all-browsers-but-ie#answer-6309833)

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var nodeName = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();

    if (e.which === 8) {
        if ((nodeName === 'input' && e.target.type === 'text') ||
            nodeName === 'textarea') {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Just put it inside your controller.

Comment: It seems a pretty neat solution. But I've already got it working with jQuery. The idea is to solve this using AngularJS, if it's possible...

Comment: angular internally uses jqLite. Nonetheless for this you just need to write javascript.

Comment: I can't backspace on password field, and I don't know the === operator. I fix it with:     if ((nodeName == 'input' && (e.target.type == 'text' || e.target.type == 'password')) ||
                    nodeName == 'textarea') {