# Is there a way to prevent backspace navigation in whole angular 2/4/5 web application?

Tags: angular, navigation, angular5

I need to restrict the backspace navigation within my whole app.Are there any solutions i.e something that I can perform under a single tile for my whole app ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent backspace from navigating back in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006000/prevent-backspace-from-navigating-back-in-angularjs)

Comment: @LokiSinclair it is not duplicate becuse of this question is related to angular2/4/5 not for angularjs.

Comment: But it is a duplicate of this, which has an answer - use canDeactivate guard. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357204/how-to-disable-browser-back-button-in-angular-2

Comment: @Shiv the solution may be slightly different, but the problem is the same. Adapt the solution to work in Angular5 = Profit!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am working on Angular 6 application and was facing same issue on Internet Explorer (IE).

I was searching the solution on internet then I found one solution in JQuery. Somehow I managed to convert it in Angular.

This snippet resolved the issue.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (
        evt.keyCode === 8 || evt.which === 8
    ) {
      let doPrevent = true;
      const types =['text','password','file','search','email','number','date','color','datetime','datetime-local','month','range','search','tel','time','url','week'];
      const target = (<HTMLInputElement>evt.target);

  const disabled = target.disabled || (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).readOnly;
  if (!disabled) {
    if (target.isContentEditable) {
      doPrevent = false;
    } else if (target.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
      let type = target.type;
      if (type) {
        type = type.toLowerCase();
      }
      if (types.indexOf(type) > -1) {
        doPrevent = false;
      }
    } else if (target.nodeName === 'TEXTAREA') {
      doPrevent = false;
    }
  }
  if (doPrevent) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. The only thing I changed in my implementation is removed `keyCode` and `which` references, because they are both deprecated. Instead, I'm checking if `$event.key == 'Backspace'`.

Comment: Nice one, It really works for me. I found the above mentioned issue in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

The solution LokiSinclair proposed for AngularJS should be adjustable to work with Angular 5 as well. The basic solution just prevents the key event, therefore you could enter a HostListener to your AppComponent which handles this globally:

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (
    evt.which === 8 && 
    ( evt.target.nodeName !== "INPUT" && evt.target.nodeName !== "SELECT" ) 
  ) { 
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Credits to [Prevent backspace from navigating back in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006000/prevent-backspace-from-navigating-back-in-angularjs) for the general logic, just translated it to the Angular 5 utilities.

Answer (score 0):

With Router Guards we can prevent users from accessing areas that they’re not allowed to access, or, we can ask them for confirmation when leaving a certain area.To control whether the user can navigate to or away from a given route, use these route guards.

You can use any of these two:

**CanActivate**
Checks to see if a user can visit a route.

**CanDeactivate**
Checks to see if a user can exit a route.

Here your preference is not to allow to to go back.
I have used for a login condition. I am giving my sample code to you. It may help you.

```
       import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
      import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
      import { AuthenticateService } from '../authenticate.service';
      import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

      @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
      })
      export class LoginAuthService implements CanActivate {

        constructor(
          private checkLogin: AuthenticateService,
          private router: Router) { }
        canActivate(
          route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
          state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
            // This isLoggedIn flag is set when the token is found after login
            if (!this.checkLogin.isLoggednIn()) {                 
              return true;
            } else {
              this.router.navigate(['/componentOfMyChoice']);
            }

        }
      }
```

Then I used it in the routing like this

```
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent , canActivate: [LoginAuthService]},
```

So when a user is logged in you cannot go back to the login page until and unless you get logged out. Hope it will help you